# How to assign the grid to a grid

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, binding, xamarin.ios, grid

I new a grid object without any settings in the xaml file.
After importing the data through 'Build_Grid()' in the 'OnAppearing()', I want to assign the 'gridview' to 'Grid_Info' to display on the screen, the code 'Grid_Info = gridview' does not work.
I am wondering how to achieve my needs?

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="AAA" />
<Grid x:Name="Grid_Info">
</Grid>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>


    void Build_Grid(Data data)
        {
        Grid gridview = new Grid();
        gridview.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = 40 });
        gridview.Children.Add(data[0],0,0);
        ...
Grid_Info = gridview; //it does not work...
        }

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
Data data = new Data();
...
Build_Grid(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you've already defined the Grid in XAML there is no need to do this

```
Grid gridview = new Grid();
```

instead just reference `Grid_Info` directly

```
Grid_Info.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = 40 });
Grid_Info.Children.Add(data[0],0,0);
```

Comment: Hi Jason, because I have to get the data in the OnAppearing(), and I have to change the grid content when the data is changed. So I want to refresh the grid content by Build_Grid() and then assign the grid to 'Grid_Info' to show. If I use the way you recommend, I do not know how to reset the Grid_Info and change the new grid to show.

Comment: `Grid_Info.Children.Clear()`

Comment: Hi Jason, 
Although the approach you suggested was not the direction I wanted to try originally. But this method has solved my problem.
Thank you so much for your kindly response!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below. I make a Data class with view to test. It work for me.

```
public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    Data[] data;
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new Data[2];
        data[0] = new Data { view = new Button() { BackgroundColor = Color.Red } }; //data[0]
        data[1] = new Data { view = new Label() { BackgroundColor = Color.Green, Text = "Label" } };//data[1]

    }
    void Build_Grid(Data[] data)
    {
        Grid gridview = new Grid();
        Grid_Info.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = 40 });
        Grid_Info.Children.Add(data[0].view, 0, 0);//show the red button
        Grid_Info = gridview; //it does not work...
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Build_Grid(data);
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public View view { get; set; }
}
```

[image]